# alert a random number including some text

Tags: javascript, math, alert

I want my alert box to have a text saying **"your request number is"** then a random number using a `math.random()` function, but it is not working

I tried this and it did not work

```
 function submitform() {
    alert("The request number is" Math.random()); 
 }
```

I also tried this and it is not working too

```
function submitform() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() *50000) + 1);
    alert("The request number is" x); 
}
```

Please help

Comment: To concatenate string you need `+` => `alert("The request number is " + Math.random())`

Comment: omg you are a life savor!! Thank you soo muuch

Comment: You should maybe think about following a starting JS tutorial

Comment: You forgot a `+` in your first code sample....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function submitform() {
     alert("The request number is "+Math.random()); 
}


function submitform() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() *50000) + 1);
    alert("The request number is "+x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please learn the concatenation first.In JavaScript it is done with + operator.
Try this

```
function submitform() {

   alert("The request number is" + Math.random()); 
}
```

and call the function

Answer (score 0):

```js
 submitform() 
  function submitform() {
     var x = Math.floor((Math.random() *50000) + 1);

      alert("The request number is"+x); 
  }
```

its small error when you need to combine a variable and text means add +symbol in between know it works    alert("The request number is"+x);

Answer (score -2):

you can use this function to get random number with string

```
function getRandomNumber(){
    return Date.now(); // :-D 
}

alert("string-" + getRandomNumber());
```

Comment: well it says the random number with text so i am just giving him the better result for generating unique request number

Answer (score -2):

You can use the es6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function submitform() {
    alert(`The request number is ${Math.random()}`);
}
```